# dompdf: Image with png format not visible in PDF

Tags: pdf, dompdf

I have image in png format that won't display in PDF which rendered using dompdf.

But if using jpg/jpeg image format, it displayed perfectly fine in the PDF.

Does anyone knows why png format image won't display in the PDF by using dompdf?

Thanks.

[image using jpeg format in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjTAi.png)

Comment: PNG isn't a supported image format in PDF. In fact JPEG and JPEG2000 are the only supported image **file formats**, in general PDF files contain raw bitmap data which is compressed with various filter, such as Flate, JBIG2, CCITT etc and an associated dictionary containing the image properties (width, height, bits, colour space etc). Since you haven't posted a link to the PDF file which doesn't work there's not much more I can say.